# Не работает условие jquery, подскажите

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#geo-world").click(function () {
        if (!$.cookie(cName, 0)) {
            $.cookie(cName, 0, {
                expires: 100,
                path:    '/'
            });
            location.reload();
            } else {
            $('#choose-loc').addClass('close-animation').delay(300).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass('close-animation');
                $(this).removeClass('open-animation');
                next();
            });
        }
    });
```

При нажатии должна записываться кука (она записывается), если она уже есть, надо просто закрыть окно. Это условие не срабатываает и страница все равно перезагружается. Вообще не понимаю что я сделала не так.

```js
$("#geo-ok").click(function () {
        if ($.cookie(cName, 0)) {
            $.cookie(cName, 1, {
                expires: 100,
                path:    '/'
            });
            location.reload();
            } else {
            $('#choose-loc').addClass('close-animation').delay(300).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass('close-animation');
                $(this).removeClass('open-animation');
                next();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `if (typeof $.cookie(cName)==='undefined'){...$.cookie(cName, 1, {... `

Comment: Спасибо, вроде помогло. А как быть если мне надо по второй кнопке заменить значение куки и точно так же проверять ее наличие по клику?  внес новый код в вопрос

Comment: Напишите функцию или просто через запятую добавьте второй эл-т для клика `$(" #geo-ok , #secondId ").click(....);`